# Airflow Webserver connecting to wrong database?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using AirFlow version `1.10.10` and am running both `airflow webserver` and `airflow scheduler` as `kubernetes pods`. Ideally I want to also run a `postgresql` db for airflow in a separate pod.

The problem is that when `airflow webserver` loads my DAGs, it logs the following before crashing:

```sh
...
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)                                                                                                                                                                   
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: connection                                    
[SQL: SELECT connection.conn_id AS connection_conn_id                                                                    
FROM connection GROUP BY connection.conn_id]
```

What I don't understand is which database is it using to for this SQL query? From the log `no such table: connection` I'm assuming that there's a db running but when/how was it created?

I haven't done anything like `airflow initdb` or something. Also I have checked processes in the container with `ps` and all the ports that are used, but found nothing database-like (the only processes that were running and ports that were used were webserver related.

Any idea/suggestion about what's happening? I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Notice your error is `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: connection`, indicating that sqlalchemy is using an `sqlite3` database. This means that you have connected to the wrong database. If you intended to connect to sqlite3, it's not shared among pods, so whatever sqlite3 database the migrations run on, is not the same one that your worker is connected to. Likely it's a different database file on each pod, not connected by volumes - and so the tables don't exist.

By default, airflow uses sqlite3. See [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html?highlight=sqlite3%20default#choosing-database-backend). So it means that airflow cannot find your database connection string, which you can set with this environment variable `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN`.